# Error when updating a package with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I get an issue when I try to update a specific package with NPM.

My command : sudo npm update -g express

My error :

```
npm WARN package.json connect-form@0.2.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ejs@0.6.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json kontroller@0.0.9-16 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ladder@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json progress@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json spawn-command@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json wizard@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json connect-redis@1.4.5 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json uglify-js@2.2.4 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm ERR! Error: EMFILE, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/asset-rack/node_modules/less/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! Error: EMFILE, too many open files
npm ERR!     at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:266:28)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/update.js:27:20
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:33:30
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:100:22
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:96:73
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:53:40
npm ERR!     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:82:32)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "express"

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:266
  log.error("cwd", process.cwd())
                           ^
Error: EMFILE, too many open files
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:266:28)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:272:26)
```

Where is the issue and is there a command to update all our packages ?

Anthony

Comment: See [this bugreport](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3433) and how the bugreporter fixed the issue (by using `ulimit -n 1000` in their shell to increase the number of open files allowed)

Comment: Ok thank you. It works with the following command "ulimit -n 1000".

Comment: You can store that command in your shells startup file (`~/.bash_profile` usually) so it will be executed automatically when you start a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this by deleting your `node_modules` folder and then trying `node install`. Not sure tho?